Georeferenced Image from the drone operation info
I am trying to perform georeferencing on a push broom drone image. I have the GPS coordinates for the center of each row (see the attached CSV file). However, my current approach isn't working, as I cannot determine the skew or rotation of the image. I now know the Ground Sampling Distance (GSD) is 5.56 cm/pixel.
How can I use the GSD to calculate the GPS coordinates of the four corners of the image and use these points as Ground Control Points (GCPs) for georeferencing?
Here is the Google Shared Link which contain the image and the csv file.
--
Camera Specification:

Focal Length: 25mm
FOV: 25 Degree
Pixel Size: 5.86um x 5.86um
CMOS size: 11.3mm

Capture Height: 60 meters

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
